# C/C++ reading and writing long strings to files

Tags: c++, c, file

I have a list of cities that I'm formatting like this:

```
{town, ...}, 
{...},
...
```

Reading and building each town and creating town1, town2,.... works
The problem is when I output it, 1st line works {town, ...}, but the second line crashes.
Any idea why?

I have [region] [town] (excel table).

So each region repeats by how many towns are in it.
Each file has 1 region/town per line.

judete contains each region repeated 1 time.

```
AB
SD
PC
....
```

orase contains the towns list.

```
town1
town2
....
```

orase-index contains the region of each town

```
AB
AB
AB
AB
SD
SD
SD
PC
PC
...
```

I want an output like this {"town1", "town2", ...} and each row (row 5) contains the town that belong to the region from judete at the same row (row 5).

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char judet[100][100];
char orase[50][900000];
char oras[100], ceva[100];

void main ()
{

    int i=0, nr;
    FILE *judete, *index, *ORASE, *output;
    judete = fopen("judete.txt", "rt");
    index = fopen("orase-index.txt", "rt");
    ORASE = fopen("orase.txt", "rt");   
    output = fopen("output.txt", "wt");

    while( !feof(judete) )
    {
        fgets(judet[i], 100, judete);
        i++;
    }

    nr = i;
    char tmp[100];
    int where=0;

    for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
        strcpy(orase[i],"");

    while( !feof(index) )
    {
        fgets(tmp, 100, index);
        for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
        {
            if( strstr(judet[i], tmp) )
            {
                fgets(oras, 100, ORASE);
                strcat(ceva, "\"");
                oras[strlen(oras)-1]='\0';
                strcat(ceva, oras);
                strcat(ceva, "\", ");
                strcat(orase[i], ceva);
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    char out[900000];

    for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
    {
        strcpy(out, "");
        strcat(out, "{");
        strcat(out, orase[i]); //fails here
        fprintf(output, "%s},\n", out);
    }

}
```

The result I get from running the code is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00D4F7A9 (msvcr110d.dll) in orase-judete.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00A90000.

Comment: How does it crash? What happens if you run it through `gdb`?

Also, Don't use strcat/strcpy. Use the `n` versions (`strncpy`,etc)

Comment: Can you please give a small sample of the judete.txt ?

Comment: @OliverMatthews `strncpy()` isn't any better than `strcpy()`, it just has a different fallacy.

Comment: @H2CO3 It still cuts off the main mistake that most people make with it.

Comment: This needs debugging.  It's got strlen() in it, so I don't want to touch it.

Comment: What does it say when it crashes?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00D4F7A9 (msvcr110d.dll) in orase-judete.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00A90000.

Comment: Do any lines in your input ever come close to 100 chars?

Comment: No, not even 50 I guess. Probably 30 should I reduce it? Once it hit '\0' it will ignore the rest of the empty chars so it shouldn't matter

Comment: If you've got *C++*, use a [std::filestream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/). Why use a rock when you have a hammer? Especially as you've already smacked yourself in the head with the rock?

Answer (score 4):

You don't clear orase array, beacause your loop

```
for(i-0;i<nr;i++)
    strcpy(orase[i],"");
```

by mistake ('-' instead of '=') executes 0 times.

Comment: orase I'm not cleaning it as I've put nothing in it at that line, I'm just initializing it with "" just in case.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu: Read the line more carefully. I doubt it's (Even close to) the only problem, but what he's pointed to is a real problem.

Comment: OK I thought you misspelled - not me anyway the same effect, it crashes

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to start by making up your mind whether you're writing C or C++. You've tagged this with both, but the code looks like it's pure C. While a C++ compiler will accept most C, the result isn't what most would think of as ideal C++.

Since you have tagged it as C++, I'm going to assume you actually want (or all right with) C++ code. Well written C++ code is going to be enough different from your current C code that it's probably easier to start over than try to rewrite the code line by line or anything like that.

The immediate problem I see with doing that, however, is that you haven't really specified what you want as your output. For the moment I'm going to assume you want each line of output to be something like this: `"{" <town> "," <town> "}"`.

If that's the case, I'd start by noting that the output doesn't seem to depend on your `judete` file at all. The `orase` and `orase-index` seem to be entirely adequate. For that, our code can look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// a class that overloads `operator>>` to read a line at a time:
class line { 
    std::string data;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) { 
        return std::getline(is, l.data);
    }
    operator std::string() const { return data; }
};

int main() {
    // open the input files:
    std::ifstream town_input("orase.txt");
    std::ifstream region_input("orase-index.txt");

    // create istream_iterator's to read from the input files. Note
    // that these iterate over `line`s, (i.e., objects of the type
    // above, so they use its `operator>>` to read each data item).
    //
    std::istream_iterator<line> regions(region_input), 
                                towns(town_input), 
                                end;

    // read in the lists of towns and regions:
    std::vector<std::string> town_list {towns, end};
    std::vector<std::string> region_list {regions, end};

    // write out the file of town-name, region-name:
    std::ofstream result("output.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<town_list.size(); i++) 
        result << "{" << town_list[i] << "," << region_list[i] << "}\n";
}
```

Noe that since this is C++, you'll typically need to save the source as `something.cpp` instead of `something.c` for the compiler to recognize it correctly.

Edit: Based on the new requirements you've given in the comments, you apparently want something closer to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// a class that overloads `operator>>` to read a line at a time:
class line { 
    std::string data;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) { 
        return std::getline(is, l.data);
    }
    operator std::string() const { return data; }
};

int main() {
    // open the input files:
    std::ifstream town_input("orase.txt");
    std::ifstream region_input("orase-index.txt");

    // create istream_iterator's to read from the input files. Note
    // that these iterate over `line`s, (i.e., objects of the type
    // above, so they use its `operator>>` to read each data item).
    //
    std::istream_iterator<line> regions(region_input), 
                                towns(town_input), 
                                end;

    // read in the lists of towns and regions:
    std::vector<std::string> town_list (towns, end);
    std::vector<std::string> region_list (regions, end);

    // consolidate towns per region:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > consolidated;
    for (int i = 0; i < town_list.size(); i++)
        consolidated[region_list[i]].push_back(town_list[i]);

    // write out towns by region
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    for (auto pos = consolidated.begin(); pos != consolidated.end(); ++pos) {
        std::cout << pos->first << ": ";
        std::copy(pos->second.begin(), pos->second.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(output, "\t"));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }       
}
```

Comment: I have a C++ project (just because) but your code contains errors and I dont know much (if any) C++ to correct them, also about judete file I need it as I want each row (row 5) to contain the towns belonging to that row (row 5)

Comment: I tagged it as C++ because I bellive C++ coders can also help me.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu: If you're getting errors trying to compile the code above, chances are that your compiler is just too old. The code above compiles cleanly with the current versions of both g++ and VC++. If you ask C++ programmers to help you, chances are they'll do as I have, and try to help you write C++...

Comment: I have visual studio 2012

Comment: win32 console application is the project type

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu: Change `std::vector<std::string> town_list {towns, end};` to `std::vector<std::string> town_list (towns, end);` (and likewise for `region_list`).

Comment: It just outputs all cities in a sigle row. I need a java String [][] format. { {...}, {...}, ... }

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `ceva` is never initialized.

Instead of using `strcpy` to initialize strings, I would recommend using static initialization:

```
char ceva[100]="";
```